# Why do I get Mathematica Hold error for this simple code?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Please look into attached files. Why do I get Hold error in the first one but not in the second? The problem seems to be in the names of variables used. Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that subscripts in Mathematica behave in unexpected ways and should be avoided. You are inviting headache just for the sake of making code look pretty.

When you do this:

```
  F:=Subscript[F,j]
```

and then evaluate `F` you probably are thinking the un-subscripted `F` is an independent symbol, but what happens is the `F` inside `Subscript[]` on the r.h.s gets evaluated with the delayed definition of `F` and so you have an infinite recursion trying to build:

```
  Subscript[Subscript[Subscript[....,j],j],j]
```

As you see in your second example if you use a different symbol on the left it works fine.

It also works fine if you dispense with the pretty formatting and do:

```
    F:=Fj
```

as now `Fj` is a plain symbol unrelated to `F`

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I suspected that subscripted names somehow relate to their unsubscripted parents. I think that if you write Subscript[F,J] (or using the pretty print version of the same) then if J is 10 then you actually get F[[10]]. This would be good if should you need it.